# Graph edges total distance

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Say one has the following graph

[image]

One has $8$ (black) vertices.

Say one has a $8 \times 1$ vector of distances between each black vertex and the red vertex. By *distances*, I mean that all my vertices are members of a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), e.g. a geographical space. Let's denote this vector by $\boldsymbol{d}$.

Say one has a $8 \times 8$ matrix in which each element represents the percentage of edge-distance in common between two vertices (*a fortiori* with entries equal to $1$ on the main diagonal and *a priori* asymmetric since two vertices are very likely to share different percentages). Let's denote this matrix by $\boldsymbol{D}$.

**Do you have any reference which explains how to compute the total distance over edges when having only $\boldsymbol{d}$ and $\boldsymbol{D}$ in hand?**

---

Starting with a very simple case, and complexifying it progressively, I ended with

$|(\boldsymbol{D}^{-1})^{'} \boldsymbol{d}|$

Where the operator $|.|$ stands for the [L$1$-norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html), i.e. the sum of all the absolute elements' value of $(\boldsymbol{D}^{-1})^{'} \boldsymbol{d}$ (although the absolute-value of entries is not needed since everything is already positive).

**Am I right by computing this (total graph) distance like this ?**

Comment: Do you by "total distance" mean the number of edges in the graph?

Comment: @wonce. No I really mean that all my vertices are members of a metric space. As if each of the vertices were a location in a geographical world.

Comment: Are you assuming your graph is a tree (so there's exactly one path from any vertex to any other vertex)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes it is a tree.